# Any idea why wp_insert_post is succeeding but not returning?

Tags: posts

I have a genuine mystery. With this code (in an ajax call):

```
file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-content/debug.log', 'Inserting new note'  . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title'    => sanitize_text_field( $title ),
            'post_status'   =>  'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'coursenote',
            'post_content'  => $_POST['data']['body']
        ), true );
        file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-content/debug.log', 'WTF'  . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

I am seeing the new post in the database, but the `wp_insert_post` function is somehow not returning (evidenced by fact that second file_put_contents is not doing anything.

I don't know if it has to do with other ajax calls or something. Just really odd that everything is fine til wp_insert_post's return.

Can anyone think of a reason why this could happen?

thanks,
Brian

**Edit:**

So I found the problem. Some really awful programmer had an `exit;` call in a `save_post` hook in a plugin. That resulted in the script not returning to the calling script (`wp_insert_post`).

That awful programmer is the author of this question :-) And the offensive `exit` is now a `return`

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error logs? I notice your code example is incomplete, not indented, and lacks context. Just because the post is in the database doesn't mean `wp_insert_post` finished, there's a lot of hooks etc that could have gone wrong. Also, when you say an AJAX call, are you talking about the modern REST API? Or the ancient Admin AJAX endpoint under `wp-admin`?

Comment: It is admin ajax. I just noticed that wp_insert_post is not resuming after the save_post do action. SO some plugin is in an infinite loop. Need to see how to return a list of all hook actions running on save_post...

Comment: query monitor can do that, but you can also disable all plugins and enable them one by one. I'd also recommend using the REST API as it brings a lot of benefits and advantages. You may even be able to use the built in endpoints and avoid having to create an endpoint at all by adding `'show_in_rest' => true` when registering the post type

Comment: Yeah, for my site mods I am doing that and in fact I want to implement this approach: https://deliciousbrains.com/wordpress-rest-api-vs-custom-request-handlers/

Comment: And one more testimony to why using exit() should be using sparingly or not at all if it can be avoided.